# Did GDAL install correctly in Winpython?

Tags: python, gdal

I installed the "gdal-201-1800-core.msi" and "GDAL-2.1.2.win32-py3.4.msi" in WinPython. It looks like the gdal could run in python shell.( there is no error when type "import gdal" ). But I could not use any gdal function such as "GetRasterband()","ReadAsArray". what's wrong with the gdal?

```
import gdal

import ogr

file=gdal.Open(r'D:\GeoNE\temp\m2000049.tif')

band=file.GetRasterBand(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a8404d484b8e> in <module>()
----> 1 band=file.GetRasterband(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

Comment: That just means GDAL couldn't open your tif. Use `gdal. UseExceptions()` to see the error message.

Comment: @Luke Such is the case! The tif without head file could not be open.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the access conditions after the name of the dataset. See [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html).
Try to mention if it is *GA_ReadOnly* or *GA_Update*, like

```
filename='D:/GeoNE/temp/m2000049.tif'    
dataset=gdal.Open(filename,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)  # opening file
```

Also check if your raster is ok in any GIS software, and try to open with gdal any another raster.

Comment: `GA_ReadOnly` is the default access if not specified. `gdal.Open(filename)` is fine, assuming `filename` can be opened.

Answer (score -3):

Try using:

```
filename = 'D:/GeoNE/temp/m2000049.tif'
file=gdal.Open(filename)
```

instead of what you have provided.

Comment: There is no more explanation to give because it's clear that the difference between the two codes is in the using of the forward slashes instead of backslashes and I used the verb "try" because I was not sure about the result. Then, I think your downvote was unnecessary.